# TimerTask not working properly

Tags: android, timertask

I set the TimerTask to run every 30 seconds but why is my TimerTask is running every few seconds instead? I would want my app to auto reload itself every 30 seconds. Is the method I am using correct? Had been facing this problem for quite a while.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
int repeatInterval = 30000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final String city = "";

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    pi = intent.getStringExtra("pi");
    Log.d("PI", pi);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

    cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityText);
    condDescr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.condDescr);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.condIcon);

    // Create and populate a List of variable names.
    String[] weather = new String[] {};
    ArrayList<String> weatherData = new ArrayList<String>();
    weatherData.addAll(Arrays.asList(weather));

    listAdapter = new WeatherAdapter(this, weatherData);

    JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { city });

    ImageButton picture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPicturePage);
    picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startPic = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    PicturePage.class);
            startPic.putExtra("date", date);
            startPic.putExtra("pi", pi);
            startActivity(startPic);
        }
    });

    repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pi", pi);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        }, 0, repeatInterval);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.selectPi1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Pi 1 is currently not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        return true;
    case R.id.selectPi2:
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i2.putExtra("pi", "pi2");
        finish();
        startActivity(i2);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

        List<NameValuePair> params2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pi", pi));

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params2));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
            Log.d("JSON OUT", response);
            if (response == null) {
                showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            uhe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e4.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);
        } catch (JSONException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            json = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            weatherD = json.getJSONArray(TAG_WEATHER);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject c = weatherD.getJSONObject(0);
            temp = c.getString(TAG_TEMP);
            nTemp = temp.replace('*', '°');
            pressure = c.getString(TAG_PRESSURE);
            humid = c.getString(TAG_HUMIDITY);
            ac = c.getString(TAG_AC);
            int aq = Integer.parseInt(ac);
            if (aq <= 150) {
                airq = "Good";
            } else if (aq <= 300) {
                airq = "Moderate";
            } else if (aq <= 500) {
                airq = "Unhealthy";
            } else if (aq <= 700) {
                airq = "Very Unhealthy";
            } else {
                airq = "HARZADOUS!";
            }
            dateO = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
            Date dateD = null;
            try {
                dateD = formatter.parse(dateO);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
            date = formatter2.format(dateD);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return weather;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
        super.onPostExecute(weather);

        Drawable day = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear_day);
        Drawable night = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear_night);
        Drawable cloud = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloudy);
        Drawable haze = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.haze);
        Drawable rain = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rain);
        Drawable thunder = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thunder);

        String code = weather.currentCondition.getIcon();

        if (code.equals("01d") || code.equals("02d")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(day);
        } else if (code.equals("01n") || code.equals("02n")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(night);
        } else if (code.startsWith("03") || code.startsWith("04")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(cloud);
        } else if (code.startsWith("09") || code.startsWith("10")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(rain);
        } else if (code.startsWith("11")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(thunder);
        } else if (code.startsWith("50")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(haze);
        }

        cityText.setText("Cyberjaya" + ", " + weather.location.getCountry()
                + " - " + pi);
        if (weather.currentCondition.getCondition().equals("Clouds")) {
            condDescr.setText("Weather: Cloudy");
            weatherS = "Cloudy";
        } else {
            condDescr.setText("Weather: "
                    + weather.currentCondition.getCondition());
            weatherS = weather.currentCondition.getCondition();
        }
        listAdapter.add("Temperature: " + "\t\t\t\t" + nTemp);
        listAdapter.add("Humidity: " + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + humid);
        listAdapter.add("Air pressure: " + "\t\t\t\t" + pressure);
        listAdapter.add("Air quality: " + "\t\t\t\t\t" + airq + " (" + ac
                + ")");
        listAdapter.add("Updated on: " + "\t\t\t\t" + date);

        pDialog.dismiss();



        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the AlarmManager. Example and usage is described here: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

This is the best way to schedule repeating tasks. But it will not run if your app has killed intentionally by the user.

---

Screening your code I think there is design flaw.

In the  `onCreate()`-method you setup your application  and create your timer to schedule in the future. After handling `onCreate()` the app will execute `onResume()` etc. But in your `TimerTask` you do call `finish()` wich will end the current activity (at some time in the future, not immediately). The next fired intent (in your TimerTask) will also first call the `onCreate` method. Beginning the loop and because it does it immediately it might be lead to the one second repeating....
So you should not finish the Activity and add an offset to the method `scheduleAtFixedRate`.
You could also check if the current intent (that called the activity) was fired by the timertask (put an extra in it) or if it was called from anywhere else (start menu) and a timertask should be created.

Comment: same problem, it reloads every second.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your timer to repeat every 10 seconds because you have put 10000 milliseconds. Try putting in a delay of like 10000 milliseconds and then change your repeatInterval variable to 30000 milliseconds to get it to repeat every 30 seconds.

I hope this helps.